# How do I prove $\neg(P\land Q)\to(\neg P\lor(\neg P\lor Q))\iff(\neg P\lor Q)$ without using a truth table?

Tags: propositional-calculus

Without using truth tables prove that
$$\neg(P\land Q)\to(\neg P\lor(\neg P\lor Q))\iff(\neg P\lor Q)$$

This is a question I've encountered during my examination.

So basically what I did was, I took the RHS of the equation which is $\neg(P\land Q)\to(\neg P\lor(\neg P\lor Q))$ and hoped I could equate it to $(\neg P\lor Q)$ even though I was sure it was not enough to prove this bi - conditional statement.

Following on my assumption, this is what I've reached

\begin{array}{rl}    &  & \neg(P\land Q)\to(\neg P\lor(\neg P\lor Q)) \iff\\    & \iff & (P\land Q)\lor(\neg P\lor Q) \iff\\    & \iff & (\neg P\lor Q\lor P) \land(\neg P\lor Q\lor Q) \iff\\   & \iff & Q \land(\neg P\lor Q) &      \end{array}

I'm kinda stuck on what to do after this, I'm not even sure whether this approach is even right.
So some help is appreciated on how to prove this bi - conditional statement.

Comment: Note that $(\neg P \lor Q \lor P)$ is a tautology.

Comment: This also depends on what rules you are allowed to use.

Comment: Well, yes indeed it's a tautology and I'd get the LHS, but how can I prove that it's a bi-conditional statement?

Comment: The rules you employed, e.g. material implication, distribution etc. goes both ways.

Comment: So this is what I just have to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{array}{rl}    &  & \neg(P\land Q)\to(\neg P\lor(\neg P\lor Q)) \iff\\    & \iff & (P\land Q)\lor(\neg P\lor Q) \iff & \quad & \text{Material Implication}\\    & \iff & (\neg P\lor Q\lor P) \land(\neg P\lor Q\lor Q) & \quad & \text{Distributive Law}\\     \end{array}

As you can verify, $\neg P \vee Q \vee P$ is a tautology.

> $$\neg P \vee Q \vee P \iff \neg P \vee P \vee Q \iff \top \vee Q \iff \top$$

Hence, we have the following.

\begin{array}{rl}    &  & \top \wedge (\neg P \vee Q \vee Q) \iff\\    & \iff & \neg P \vee Q \vee Q \iff\\    & \iff & \neg P \vee Q & \square\\     \end{array}

Comment: Thanks, but what about this bi-conditionality?

Comment: @Nimrod you are very welcome! I didn’t get the question. What bi-conditionality?

Comment: Note that these are all logical equivalences